# What do you call the metal containers used to cook food (meat, pizza etc.) in the oven? (Translation of ‘fuente’)

Tags: translation, image-identification

I'm not talking about a water fountain, nor a power source. In Spanish, both of these things,

[image]

which you can cook meat, pizza, etc. with, are called ‘fuente’ or ‘asadera’. The first is for general purposes, the second is usually used for pizza. Which are the correct translations, or at least which terms do you use for each one? For the first image I found **roasting pan**, but I don't think that term could be used for the second image. Should I call it a **pizza pan**?

Comment: How heavyweight is that second pan? If you hit someone on the head with it will you end up with (a) a dead someone or (b) a head-shaped indentation in the pan?

Comment: Generically, *pan* works. Depending on the dimensions, I'd call the second a *pie pan.*

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No, usually are very lightweight pans. Think they are of aluminium, tin or any malleable metal

Comment: If you search your favorite online store for baking tray or pizza tray you'll find many such things. A roasting pan is typically deeper for roasting meat with juices.

Comment: A *pie pan* generally is much deeper, has slanted sides, and is too small for a pizza; I'd call it a *pizza pan*.

Comment: Pizza pan is perfectly understandable and common. There's even the term pan-style pizza which means pizza cooked in a pan with edges, as opposed to being placed directly on a rack or stone. Pan-style pizza is generally thicker and may have more toppings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both could be called baking / cooking pans. [Here](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Cuisinart-18-in-Aluminum-Baking-Pan/50412930), for example, is a "Cuisinart 18-in Aluminum Baking Pan" sold by Lowe's, a major U.S. home goods retailer:

[image]

They can also be called baking sheets or cookie sheets (especially the rectangular one). (However, it might be a bit too deep and thick for that; I can't tell for certain.) [Here](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sunbeam-Sweet-Bake-3-Piece-Cookie-Sheet-Set/25737056) is a "Gibson Home Sweet Bake 3-Piece Cookie Sheet Set" sold by Walmart:

[image]

The item in your second image (which appears to have the right dimensions for making [deep-dish pizza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago-style_pizza)) can be called a "pizza pan", as you say. However, a "roasting pan" is usually deep enough to roast a whole turkey, pork loin, etc.; neither of your dishes appears to be deep enough for that.

"Baking tray" (as mentioned in another answer) can also be used.

This answer is for American English; other terms might be used in other dialects.

Comment: In BrE it would be "tray" not "pan". Baking tray for example.

Comment: In AmE I would say "baking tray" for almost all of these, unless I was calling it a "cookie sheet", but the small round one I would specifically call a "pizza pan" as a weird exception (and the style of pizza cooked in it is "pan pizza"). Normally, a "pan" to me goes on the stove, and only rarely in the oven.

Comment: @GlennWillen There must be quite a bit of regional variation or something in that, because to me, a "pan" always goes in the oven, never on the stove. Or if I'm being precise, to me the defining characteristics of a pan are roughly these: (1) significantly wider than it is tall (2) flat bottom and near-vertical sides or no sides (3) no protruding handle (4) no lid (though of course one can improvise a cover). But the dishes I've seen that meet that description are generally meant to be used in an oven.

Comment: @David, as a Brit, I find it hard to imagine a pan without a handle, and all of my saucepans have lids.  I'd never put my pans in an oven - only pots, dishes or trays.  It seems this is an area of language that varies wildly between regions.  I find it surprising that terminology varies so much; it's understandably that newer technologies such as automotive developed different language in different places, but cookery seems much longer established.

Comment: As yet another Briton, I think the distinction between "tray" and "pan" can best be determined by the height of the edge: both are common. OTOH, "sheet" is used rather less.

Comment: Based on these comments, I think that @TobySpeight is right: There is a lot of variation in terminology. The terms that I've offered are what I've often heard throughout my life, living mostly in New York City and Washington, DC.

Comment: @David As an American, I have a saucepan with a lid, a frying pan with something that could be described as a lid though is usually called a cover, and even a cake pan with a lid (for later storage of the baked foodstuff, not for use in the oven). And saucepans and frying pans almost always go on the stove and not in the oven.

Comment: @GlennWillen And for completeness, most pizza (at least where I'm from) is cooked on a big round stone, called, appropriately, a "round" or "stone."

Comment: @AR-solidarityforModstrike As an American, I do not use the word "pan" for whatever it is that you call a saucepan. The frying pan is a bit of a weird case; I do use the same term but in the taxonomy of cooking implements I would classify it as a skillet, not a pan. And as for your cake pan, I'd have to see it to say with any confidence (honestly the lid rule is less strict than the others), but I might classify that as a dish, tray, or platter, not a pan. Anyway, my point is not to try to claim that my terminology is "right" or anyone else's is "wrong", my point is that it varies widely.

Comment: I think it's down to regional preference, but there's no real difficulty understanding any of the terms. If you say sheet, tray, or pan with regard to baking cookies, nobody's going to be baffled.

Answer (score 13):

Not one word but two, they are often called **baking trays** or **baking sheets**. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/baking-tray) has

> **baking tray**
> noun, UK
> (US **baking sheet**)
> a sheet of metal with low sides, used for baking food

They show a picture of one, and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=baking+tray&tbm=isch&sa=X) are a lot more images.

Comment: In Britain lots of recipes etc refer to them as "oven trays", or "baking trays".  The ones with higher sides eg. for joints of meat etc., I think are usually called "roasting pans".

Comment: @WS2 or "roasting tins".  "Baking sheet" is also quite widely used in the UK

Answer (score 2):

Call the first one a baking tray or baking pan. The second one is a pizza dish /pan. At least that's what I call them.